# WebPush UnauthorizedRegistration 400 Error when try to send push notification from Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, push-notification, web-push

I am trying to send push notifications using Web Push from NodeJS. Here's how I am getting my subscription in the front-end:

```
swRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: true,
    applicationServerKey: "SOME_APPLICATION_PUBLIC_KEY"
}).....
```

Here's the NodeJS I am using to send the push notifications:

```
const webpush = require('web-push');
const options = {
  vapidDetails: {
    subject: 'mailto:SOME_MAIL_ID',
    publicKey: 'SOME_PUBLIC_KEY',
    privateKey: 'SOME_PRIVATE_KEY'
  }
};
const pushSubscription = {"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/SOME_END_POINT","keys{"p256dh":"SOME VALUE","auth":"SOME_VALUE"}};
webpush.sendNotification(pushSubscription, "Test Notification", options)
.then(function(response) { console.log(response) })
.catch(function(error) {console.log(error)});
```

Then I am getting an 400 error. I have cross verified my gcm_sender_id and my server key. Everything looks good and the notifications work properly when tested in Firefox and fail in Chrome.

Here's the error I have been getting:

```
  name: 'WebPushError',
  message: 'Received unexpected response code',
  statusCode: 400,
  headers: 
   { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
     date: 'Mon, 07 Aug 2017 13:04:32 GMT',
     expires: 'Mon, 07 Aug 2017 13:04:32 GMT',
     'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
     'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
     server: 'GSE',
     'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"',
     'accept-ranges': 'none',
     vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
     connection: 'close' },
  body: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>UnauthorizedRegistration</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>UnauthorizedRegistration</H1>\n<H2>Error 400</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n',
  endpoint: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/SOME_END_POINT'
```

I have seen that many users have this issue, but I couldn't find a proper solution documented.Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php/issues/67

Comment: @AndroidLover Nope, I tried the sendNotification() syntax options mentioned in that link, but that didn't work and those syntax do not work with Node JS

Comment: Is it a new app? Then why are you using the legacy `gcm_sender_id`? Just remove it and [reset](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2016/11/how-to-enable-or-block-push-notifications-from-your-browser-preferences/) your browser permissions (block then allow notifications). Now FCM (ex GCM) supports VAPID. If your VAPID configuration works with Firefox then it should also work fine with Chrome...